# Passing argument attributes from a JSON call into a new Modal

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a system in place with some dynamic modal code, with placeholder strings and callback attributes sent via a RESTful GET call. These values are bound to a new Backbone model:

```
ModalGroupSettings = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: "/example/index.json",
  parse: function(data) {
    console.debug("Data", data);
    return data;
  }
});
```

The part that is difficult to work around is actually passing back the attributes, as seen below

```
Strings = new ModalGroupSettings;
ExampleModal = models.ModalDialog.extend({
    title: Strings.fetch() //Returns object, not the serialized data
});
```

Given that fetch is async, what is returned is the entire backbone `Model` object with the successful HTTP Request as undigested `responseText`. What callback needs be accounted for in the Strings.fetch() call, or the Model to assure that I can access the actual parsed object, or parts of it without using JSON.Parse on the `responseText`?

Answer (score 0):

Pass a `success` callback function to the fetch call, as an option, and populate `title` on success.

```js
Strings = new ModalGroupSettings;
ExampleModal = models.ModalDialog.extend({
    title: null,
    initialize: function () {
        Strings.fetch({
            success: _.bind(function (model, response, options) {
                console.log(response); // => parsed response object
                this.title = response;
            }, this)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't necessarily expose/return an argument string for the title attribute, It would need to return a string, or else it just loads it as an Object and then do a toString() on it. I can also access the items via the object's responseText attribute but that doesn't seem productive. Any ideas on how to have it return w/o breaking async?

Comment: well, you'd have to populate the `title` *property* (note that it's not an attribute of the model), on initialization.